# Implementing data structures in golang

Tags: arrays, go, slice

So I have to implement some data structures in a language compiled to native-code. I did that in C++, but now I wanted to try another language, that I didn't worked with before. I chose `golang`. First data structure would be an array (capable of dynamic append, removal, etc.) In C++ I got something like this:

```
class array{
    int n;
    int *t;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So `n` is the number of elements and `*t` is a pointer to an array, which would be created in a constructor. I wrote `append`, `pop_back`, `remove`, `find` methods and so on. Now when I switch to golang, my first attempt was to create a `struct` something like this:

```
type array struct {
    n int
    ...
}
```

and well I didn't know what should be here instead of dots. So I did some reading (got Brian W. Kernighan book) and I found about 2 data types : `arrays` and `slices`. I found a piece of code for appending to the array (take an array, resize it (n+1) and insert a value). I tested it, works (I tested it on a built-in `slice` type). Now when I would have my own array type I don't know if I should use `slice`, or maybe something else. I have this piece of code, which would measure the times for `Append()` operation, depending on the number of elements:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type array struct {
    n int
}
func Append(slice []int, element int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    total := len(slice) + 1
    if total > cap(slice) {
        // Reallocate. Grow to 1.5 times the new size, so we can still grow.
        newSize := total*3/2 + 1
        newSlice := make([]int, total, newSize)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[:total]
    slice[n] = element
    return slice
}

func main() {
    var seconds int64 = 0
    sizes := [5]int64{1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000}
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        var j int64
        for j = 0; j < 100; j++ {
            array := make([]int, sizes[i], sizes[i]+1)
            start := time.Now()
            array = Append(array, 1)
            elapsed := time.Since(start)
            seconds += int64(elapsed)
        }
        seconds = seconds/100
        fmt.Println(seconds)
        seconds = 0
    }
    fmt.Println("The end")
}
```

I always do `array := make([]int, sizes[i], sizes[i]+1)` cuz I don't want to make capacity changing and copying be relevant here. As far as I know there should be no difference if array has 1000 elements or 100000 - the time should be approximately the same, but the results I've got are different :

```
1810
1589
46
99
244
The end
```

The times differ. Now my questions are:

1. What basic type should I use in my own array type?
2. Can I somehow reallocate the memory (increment/decrement the length) without operating on capacity?
3. Is there a way to change this algorithm to make its computional complexity `O(1)`, so it doesn't matter how many arguments are there?

Comment: *WHY* would you want to implement a dynamic array in a language that has dynamic arrays already? In Go, use slices, they *are* dynamic arrays.

Comment: Seriously, it's like trying to write your own list implementation in Python.

Comment: Well I study at University, so what I have to do, I do

Comment: I don't think there is any benefit in implementing data types already available in the language like arrays, slices and maps. You will get into chicken and egg problems. Maybe try some more complicated data structures.

Comment: Go's testing package has benchmarking which is what you should use for timing tests.

Comment: The base type for implementing a dynamic array is a static array. If you really want to, use Go's basic array as the base type. That is what a Go slice does, after all. A Go slice is a pointer to the array, a capacity and a length.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But can I reallocate memory for a static array in Go (like with `new/delete[]` in C++?

Comment: Go is a garbage collected language.  Memory management is done for you. It even handles whats on the stack or the heap. Read Here  https://deferpanic.com/blog/manual-memory-management-in-go/

Comment: @Frynio: You declare a new, bigger array and then copy the old array into it. Just like you do in C++.

Comment: @ZanLynx, using `make()`?

Comment: @Frynio No, `make` creates a slice. Basic arrays are a part of the Go language and you just use `var arr [1024]byte`